# cron expression - execute task every day of the week starting from an hour and every x hours

Tags: cron

I am trying to build a cron expression.

I need to execute a task every day of the week, from 5PM Monday to 5PM Friday, starting from 5PM Monday and every twelve hours until reaching 5PM Friday.

How can I do this?

Also, Is there a good tutorial to learn how cron expression are built?